# Verify that mobile phone number is accociated with an active PayPal account

Tags: paypal

Is there PayPal API endpoint that verifies that a given mobile phone number is associated with an active PayPal account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PayPal API for verifying phone numbers.